# syntax error while compling php progam (unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';')

Tags: php

I am working on hashing a string and getting a hasnumber and then unhasing a number to get a string back. Below is my java version of it:

```
public class Hashcode {
  private static final String ALPHABET = "acegikmnoprstuvy";

  public static long hash(String s) {
    long h = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      h = (h * 37 + ALPHABET.indexOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    return h;
  }

  public static String unhash(long n) {
    String result = "";
    while (n > 7) {
      result = ALPHABET.charAt((int) (n % 37)) + result;
      n = n / 37;
    }
    if (n != 7) {
      System.err.println("Error, hash parity incorrect.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hash("reports"));
    System.out.println(unhash(690336378753L));
    System.out.println(unhash(932246728227799L));
    System.out.println(hash("mymitsapp"));
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to do same exercise in php as shown below but it is giving me an error:

```
function unhash($h) {  
    $letters = "acegikmnoprstuvy";
    $s='';
    while ($h>7){
        //hold
        $pos = fmod($h, 37);
        $s = $letters[$pos].$s;
        $h = ($h-$pos) / 37 ;
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Below is an error and here is the [ideone](http://ideone.com/VyVBDp) link.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/mNw4IK/prog.php on line 16

Any thoughts what is wrong or any other better way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it is expecting either `,` or `;`.

You have:

```
echo $something
```

but it should be:

```
echo $something;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user1234 That goes outside the scope of this question.